# combining css classes to target specific pages

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I have a class `.entry-content` that has `30px` of `margin` on every page, and I have a class `.double-outter-wrapper` that is the `first-child`, but is only on 1 or 2 pages.  Is there a way to target only the pages that have `.entry-content` and `.double-outter-wrapper` to change the `margin` to `0`?

Comment: You cannot modify the styles of a parent based on the presence of a child element, if that's what you're asking. Since you're using WordPress though, you could style your `.entry-content` differently based on the page name, which should be included as a class in your `body` tag.

Comment: As @JonUleis says, you cannot target an element based on its child, but you can target it based on the page - WP adds classes for the page/post id to the body (and some themes also add the page slug), so you can use this to target `entry-content` in specific pages

Comment: can you try this with JQUERY:  $(".double-outter-wrapper").parent(".entry-content").css("margin","0");

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript may be a viable solution if you're willing to use it... if you include a common JavaScript GUI controller in each of your pages you can definitely handle this... it's as simple as...

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('your-conditional-element').length !== 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('your-element')[0].style.margin = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery want to achieve the same. So here class one has a background color red. And in the two cases, it has a class `two`. So selecting the class `two` and checking for its parent `one` and changing its CSS to green. You can add CSS as per your need like `margin:0`
Here is an example

```js
$(".two").parent(".one").css("background","green");
```

```css
.one {
  background:red;
  width:90%;
  height:20%;
  margin:30px;
  padding:20px;
}
.two {
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.three {
  background:orange;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two three">
    class 1
    </div>
  <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two three">
    </div>
  <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="one">
  
  <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="one">
  
  <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>
```